# How to query a string from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

As we can see, column definition is a SQL query, which will produce two columns: `id` and `code`.

My question is how to execute the SQL query in definition and only get column `code`?

the Shorter, the better.

Comment: `select code from .... `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the query by doing:

```
select 'select code from (' ||
       concat_ws(' union all ', definition) ||
       ') u'
from t
where . . .;
```

Unfortunately, SQL does not allow direct execution of the statement, except in the function block where you can use `execute using`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for PostgreSQL:

```
select replace(definition,'id,','') as definition_updated from acad_object_groups;

result:
                      definition_updated
--------------------------------------------------------------
 select code from programs where offeredby=89 and career='UG'
 select code from programs where offeredby=89 and career='PG'
```

This gives the modified queries with only the `code` column. These can then be run individually via an application.

If you want to actually execute each `definition` column value itself as a SQL command, and then only retrieve the `code` column, the following can be used. The number of such queries to be executed individually will be the number of values existing in `definition` column:

```
select code from (execute-value-from-existing-definition-column);

example:
select code from (select id,code from programs where offeredby=89 and career='UG') as a;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the query in the 'definition' column as the table to select from

```
SELECT code FROM 
(select id, code from programs where offeredby=89 and career='PG') AS definiton_query
```

Another option would be to do some pattern recognition and extract the where clause from the 'definition' column and combine it with "SELECT code FROM programs" and then execute that command